# Which language features are considered harmful?

Tags: programming-languages, bug, features, mistakes

Please, **explain why** and list which languages have the (mis)feature implemented As far you know.

Post what you consider a harmful feature, not what you dislike.

Comment: [Goto considered harmful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful).

Comment: @sbi You can also read in the same page "XMLHttpRequest Considered Harmful" ...

Comment: All of them are considered harmful, by somebody or other, with the possible exception of basic expressions.

Comment: ["Considered Harmful" Essays Considered Harmful](http://meyerweb.com/eric/comment/chech.html)

Comment: @David Thornley: `a = 1/0` - basic expression, harmful. ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Allow Null by default, the "trillion"* dollar mistake. Sorry Tony Hoare.
Almost every language available on planet.

[Tony Hoare explains](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare)

*I adjusted the expression coined by Tony Hoare to reflect actual loss on these days :-)

Comment: This is not a feature or a mistake, but rather, a lack of feature. Having non-nullable reference types is not something you can lightly drop into a language; It requires a lot of thought and good design, and is very hard to do in a way that doesn't feel like fighting with the compiler. Spec# and Singularity show how hard it is.

Comment: @imgx86, no, it's definitely a mistake. Non-nullable reference types are a feature added in response to the null mistake to allow compatibility with a type system that ordinarily allows null.

Comment: @Kyralessa: Perhaps he wants to be sure that HoLyVieR gets the Populist badge? :-) I agree, it makes no sense to accept your own answer like this.

Answer (score 37):

### Register Globals in PHP

Information : http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

This is by far the worst feature to be ever implemented for readability reasons and security reasons. Basicly all the GET parameter received are transformed into variables.

For example with this URL : /index.php?value=foobar

You can do the following :

```
<?php
echo $value; // return foobar
?>
```

When you are reading code, it is very confusing to know where the variable comes from.

Also if the feature is misused, it can lead to security hole. Here's a code example from php.net that shows how it can be misused :

```
<?php
// define $authorized = true only if user is authenticated
if (authenticated_user()) {
    $authorized = true;
}

// Because we didn't first initialize $authorized as false, this might be
// defined through register_globals, like from GET auth.php?authorized=1
// So, anyone can be seen as authenticated!
if ($authorized) {
    include "/highly/sensitive/data.php";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thats horrible. While I can understand the want, keeping it on by default made absolutely no sense

Comment: It should be noted and emphasized that register globals has not been enabled by default since PHP 4.2 (all the way back in 2000), is deprecated in PHP 5.3 (2009) and will be removed entirely in PHP 6, but people *still* keep going back to the "OMG register globals" well even after 10 years.

Comment: Pretty Hopeless PHP

Comment: @SHiNKiROU It's not hopeless, that feature was deprecated and will be removed in PHP 6.

Comment: It's not hopeless, it's just so far behind so many other languages that the only reason anybody uses it is because it was until recently a lot easier to get cheap webhosting for it than other languages.

Answer (score 18):

C and C++ MACROS.  If I ever have to see another compiler error due to someone choosing a standard function name for their macro which screws up my code I'm going to scream.  Let's see the last offending one:

```
#define vector(int) new VARIANT[int];
```

Aaarg!  What have you done with my STL vector!?

Comment: Namespacing is one of the things that makes typedefs and templates immediately more friendly.

Comment: Agreed, but only because modern languages have found replacements for the functionality of textual macros.  Back when they were invented, macros were a Good Thing because compiler technology was so primitive.

Comment: where did you find this macro?

Comment: @dsimcha - I don't know about this.  Lisp macros have been around for a long time.

Comment: +1 For denouncing C++ macros, they are overused to the point where the entire code seems to be in shorthand.

Comment: @Jason:  I'm not knocking Lisp-style "real" AST macros, which are still useful and cool.  I only hate C/C++-style macros that work purely at the textual level, have no concept of scope, allow one to create ridiculously leaky abstractions and obfuscated code, and can be completely made obsolete by more modern features, one of which, ironically, is "real" macros.

Comment: Macros are excellent feature in C. You just need to know how to use them.

Comment: #define true false

Answer (score 14):

Fallthrough by default in C and C++ switch statements.

Comment: This is always a *helpful* feature in all of the code I've written. How is this a misfeature?

Comment: This has gotta be one of my *favorite* parts of `switch`... Without fallthrough, there are far more flexible ways of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: @greyfade: It's helpful until you forget the `break` statement, or someone adds a case between two cases (or re-orders them), not noticing there was fall-through between them.  I don't see any way that fallthrough is better than the C# way of requiring either a break or goto case, etc.

Comment: Duff's Device scoffs at your impunity!

Comment: i agree. By default is not a good feature.

Comment: Without fallthrough, things like daysInMonth() would take waaaay more code.

Comment: Does no one read? He said fallthrough BY DEFAULT

Comment: I use it a lot - but always comment fallthroughs.  I don't see the harm.

Comment: Fallthrough is an excellent feature; having it as a default rather than requiring it to be told to do it isn't.  However... so many heavily used C-derivative languages do it that programmers are used to it and should be especially aware of the risk.  I'm not a fan of the compiler hand-holding and nannying the coder.

Answer (score 13):

Implicit type conversions when the types being converted between have no obvious relationship. For example, converting a random, non-numerical `string` into an `int`, like in PHP.

Comment: Should be noted that once you get your head around it, this sort of thing becomes a non-issue. It's only really a problem if you don't do any checks in critical areas for user entered values, but is infinitely useful if, say, you know something will be a number, but comes as a string. For example, a field from a DB will likely be returned as a string, and you don't want to worry about casting it.

Comment: @Slokun: Can you come up with a better example? Why store integral values in a db using a string type?

Comment: @SnOrfus Getting a number passed in a URL, user input, functions, and other things common to non-statically typed languages.

Comment: This is also a problem in C, since a quoted string's value is a pointer, which can be converted to an integer, and this can make constructs that look like they might make sense compile properly but produce nonsense.  In C++, you can define conversion functions with the keyword `explicit`, which stops implicit type conversions, but there's still problems.

Comment: @TheLQ: If it's user input,  you have to validate it to figure out if it's a number.  Like @Slokun said.  If you're reading data from a file, you can kind of expect numeric data to be where it's supposed to, but having an exception get raised in the case of disk corruption is often better than just having a random `0` for some value.

Answer (score 12):

[goto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto): although ok in rare cases, it is more often misused and leads to hard to read programs.

Comment: Good god yes. http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: I've seen the opposite where allowing the judicious use of goto would have saved a program from being 3 million lines of code.

Comment: Ah, hyperbole... A valid literary technique.

Answer (score 11):

NONE

Just because a feature gets misused frequently does not make it harmful.

IMHO the entire "is considered harmful" is the [Reductio ad Hitlerum](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Reductio_ad_Hitlerum) of programming language discussions.

Most, if not all, of the "harmful" features have, or had originally, a very valid use case or are simply convenience methods in the first place.  It is up to the developers to understand the pros and cons and code accordingly.

If your questions was meant to be something along the lines of "what language features have common pitfalls or unfortunate side-effects" my answer would be different.

[edit] To be clear: I do not mean the continued use of deprecated methods.  If the developers are depreciating/removing a feature you should use the replacement.  I am referring to concept that a current part of the language is considered harmful because some do not like what it encourages or the trade-off involved in using it that many people discuss.

Comment: I disagree, a good counter example is my answer. PHP register global was just bad, no mater how you use them. This is why it has been deprecated and strongly advise to never use on older version of PHP.

Comment: Had to read up on that one, but the link in the answer that mentions it agrees with my point "This page will explain how one can write insecure code with this directive but keep in mind that the directive itself isn't insecure but rather it's the misuse of it."  The link also mentions it is depreciated, which is not what I was meaning, so I edit accordingly.

Comment: +1 Put in wrong hands, any language construct is harmful.

Comment: @mouviciel - that is probably the most concise way to put the point

Comment: Good point... even if 95% of gotos are bad, the feature itself is still worth having for the other 5%

Comment: HoLyVieR: i agree. good example. Also with gotos, i believe if there were additional language constructs you can get rid of all reasons to use them. Also i believe there are ways to get rid of MANY macros (but not all, even tho i said all gotos can be gotten rid of)

Comment: I think it's more like putting the ejector seat button next to the radio on/off button. The feature itself might not be bad, but not preventing harm by accidental use of it is.

Comment: I am all for making the dangerous stuff spew warnings or be a lot harder to get at.  I just find it backward that some people would presume to remove a feature just because it has bit them too many times without proposing an alternative that performs the same function with the same level of execution efficiency.  I have often thought that in many of these situations it would be useful to have an "unsafe" namespace like some of the .net languages have for unmanaged and move all of the questionable functions in there to make it VERY obvious, but I would never remove them without a replacement.

Comment: I think this is the programming equivalent of "guns don't kill people, people do".

Comment: Excellent point, I wish I had a +10 vote :)

Comment: "fool-proofness" has no value? Every manager knows he will have morons or drunk programmers working on his code at some point.

Comment: @Pavel I agree, and in 99% of cases I would fxcop the crap out of anyone using a goto on my projects but that still does not make me want the word removed.  

Also, a fool proof programming language would either be nearly useless it had so few functions or be completely underestimating the scale of fools' power to do the foolish.

Answer (score 7):

Autovivification (or other bind-variable-on-(assign|use) feature) is the feature which I've found to give me the most bugs.

Comment: +1 - We may not agree on iterator sugar but this is something I can agree with 100%.

Answer (score 7):

`PLEASE` in INTERCAL. Don't use it enough, it complains. Use it too much, it complains.

Comment: That language is not supposed to be used seriously. It was created to be a very 'unique' programming language, so it is full of things (e.g. comefrom - just on top of my mind) that don't make sense.

Comment: I thought that it would be obvious, but yes, I am aware that it's not a serious language.

Comment: Sorry, some people are too serious around here.

Comment: Just discovered the language last week on Wikipedia and was blown away of how popular it was (and still ist O_O).

Comment: There are a number of "challenge" languages and they are always popular, because coders tend to do the job because of a love of the chase.  Also very popular for interview questions as they are deliberately obtuse, thought provoking and hard.

Answer (score 7):

Although some folks disagree with the man or various things he says, a lot of Douglas Crockford's *JavaScript: The Good Parts* is basically this question applied to JS.  Amongst Crockford's complaints:

- Global scope by default for everything (DC shows how to use function/objects as namespaces and scope delimiters to wrangle this in.)
- Statements like `with`, whose failure behavior is to define things at the global namespace. (Gah! Its like the JS motto is if you fail, then *fail as hard as possible*!)
- Unexpected behavior with the `==` operator, which basically requires you to always use the `===` operator.
- Semicolon insertion.

Really a whole lot of JS should be considered harmful, maybe even the whole language, but the good parts are just so darn good that it kind of makes up for it (at least for me.)

Answer (score 6):

### "Failing silently" in Flash Player as default behavior

Ok, not really a feature of the language itself but still pretty closely related.

Suddenly your Flash/Flex application stops working and nobody can give you the slightest hint what the f* has happened. No error message, no stacktrace, no nothing. It's just that suddenly the screen transition doesn't happen (or happens in a completely wrong way), or buttons don't react to clicks any longer, or comboboxes are empty instead of being populated with some entries.

That "feature" alone is responsible for several [shrug reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2353466#2353466) and a whole bunch of gray hair I've been getting. -.- While popping up some cryptic message in the user's face isn't desirable either, it can at least help the developer getting the problem fixed.

But Flash Player leaves you stabbing around in the dark, relying on the user's description (while the problem may actually originate from a completely different location in the code that doesn't have anything to do with what the user was doing). Only if you use the Debug Player you actually get the popup window with an error message and a stacktrace.

However, it can be quite interesting to watch flash embedded movies on certain news sites and get repeated messages about Null references from the used embedded player SWF. :D

Comment: iPhone apps also crash without warning sometimes, in certain weird timings

Comment: Failing silently in *anything* is pretty lousy.

Answer (score 6):

In C/C++: That assignments are also expressions COMBINED WITH the very similar assignment = and comparison == operators. Not a harmful feature per se, but it's way to easy to introduce (sometimes subtle) bugs by accidentally mistyping the operator.

```
int i = 10;

someCode();

if(i = 5)
{
    /* We don't want this block to be executed, but it is */
    moreCode();
}
```

Comment: ...combined with the fact that an integer or a pointer is a valid condition.

Answer (score 5):

Access modifiers in Java with package private language default and private programming convention default.

Answer (score 5):

Replacing undefined variables by an empty string in shell without any warnings: `rm -rf $nosuchvar/*`.

Comment: +1 Argh! LOL - horrific default (and amusing / scary example)

Comment: @Orbling something like `${varname:-/dev/null}` may be a workaround...

Comment: Well it goes to show the need for always defensively checking variable existence and content before usage.

Answer (score 4):

The ability to turn counterclockwise in LOGO.  Wtf, lets just turn clockwise `360 - x` degrees.

Comment: Well, it's been a while since I used LOGO.  Why is this harmful?

Comment: Logo can be used to control a real, physical turtle robot. Sometimes you *want* the turtle to turn a specific direction, or to turn more than once. For example, maybe you’re programming it to do some kind of dance.

Comment: @Mason, It was supposed to be a joke.

Comment: @Dan, See above comment.

Comment: Fair enough! It did seem a bit of an odd complaint :P

Comment: Yeah, especially in LOGO For Clocks.

Comment: @int, I'm glad someone is getting the joke.

Comment: I love Logo (see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/21028/which-language-did-you-love-from-heart/21063#21063) and it is an excellent teaching language, particularly for young people.  When I was say 11 and first used Logo most of my class did not know that much geometry, but they got told 90 was a quarter turn and know left from right.  So it isn't a negative feature - the same as why we don't multiply by reciprocals instead of having a divide operator.  Yes, I know it's a joke.

Answer (score 4):

### Stopping Thread from an other Thread

In Java and in other language you could stop a thread from an other one arbitrarily without giving the time for the thread you stopped to finish properly. This ability have been [deprecated](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28java.lang.Throwable%29) considering the huge amount of problem it could bring in nearly all situation.

Comment: While I suppose this *can* be harmful, there are times it's extremely useful (e.g., a debugger supporting single stepping and  break points).

Comment: @Jerry Debugging is an entire other thing, it doesn't stop the process, it pauses it.

Comment: rather the contrary, it stops the thread. Apparently, you're talking about *killing* the thread, not just stopping it though. That is a bit harder to justify...

Comment: I don't see this as necessarily being a language feature though.  More a standard library thing.

Answer (score 4):

**[Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in PHP**

Just because you `$can` doesn't mean you `$$should`

Comment: As usual, Perl... has the (potentially dangerous) feature available, has an easy best-practice way to turn it off (`use strict`) and an easy way to turn it on again in exactly the cases you'd want it (`no strict 'refs'`).

Comment: I have never found a use to have a dynamic variable name. And the only times I did, it made the code unreadable and a WTF moment a few months later when I revisited the code.

Comment: Mmm, applications include metaprogramming with other peoples' obnoxious package variables or the symbol table (which is a liittle different, I suppose).

Comment: this can be usefull... but most of the time is not.

Comment: Unless of course `$can == $$should`.

Comment: @Joe I would challenge you to show me *one* example where variable variables make a solution clearer.

Comment: The comment *was* meant as a joke, sorry I didn't make that clear, but since you ask [here is the best example where variable variables make a solution clearer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003605/when-to-use-a-variable-variable-in-php/1003638#1003638). I'll admit it's a rather bad example though.

Comment: @Joe Oh, sorry, I thought it was literal, because it received a down vote for the answer. I guess someone else also didn't *get* the joke either :P

Answer (score 3):

The `With` statement in Delphi comes to mind, although there are cases when it's usefull.

Comment: A good case when I ported something from Delphi to Lazarus and my TControl descendant contained "with Canvas do ... Width, Height" referencing the control sizes, but Lazarus TCanvas had its own Width and Delphi, so this led to wrongly compiled code

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in AWK starting at index **1**!

Comment: Arrays in C and C++ starting at index 0!

Comment: Arrays in lisp starting at index `car`! :P

Comment: In Lua as well — unforgiveable!

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, **scalar context vs. list context** can be tricky. It's got some good points that make certain operations convenient, but occasionally you run into something terrible, like *completely changing the meaning of an operator* (potentially from a significant distance away in the code).

```
sub foo { (1..5) }
my @list = foo();           # (1,2,3,4,5)
my $length = scalar @list;  # 5. the length of the list.
my $length2 = scalar foo(); # '' (the empty string. because it's false)
```

That's just not right.

*(It arises from trying to make something that acts sort of like the regular range operator, so you can say something in a loop like `next if /start_regex/ .. /end_regex/`).*

Comment: Man that is *so* confusing. The worst thing about learning Perl was trying to get my head around that.

Comment: I always thought anything that allows a function to return in multiple ways was a handy convenience.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.x's relative import syntax.  Suppose I have a package `x.plugins` that adds support for various other libraries for `x`.  And suppose I have a `sqlalchemy` module in `x.plugins` so I can add sqlalchemy support to `x`.  What do you think will happen if I add the following line to sqlalchemy.py?

```
import sqlalchemy
```

The answer is that the module will try to import itself.  What this syntax does is essentially make it impossible to import the actual global sqlalchemy package.  Python 2.5 added a way to specify that this is a relative import:

```
from . import sqlalchemy
```

...but it isn't until Python 3 that the first syntax was actually gotten rid of (although it can be disabled in Python 2.6+ with `from __future__ import absolute_import`).

Answer (score 1):

FORTRAN common blocks.  If you made a simple mistake, one part of an application could clobber another part's globals.

FORTRAN assigned goto statement / COBOL alter statement.  Self-modifying code.  Danger, warning, flying spaghetti monsters!!

Comment: FORTRAN did not have an ALTER statement.  FORTRAN had the ASSIGN statement, with the assigned GOTO.  COBOL had the ALTER statement, which served a similar purpose.

Comment: @John - thanks.  My memory of assign/alter is dim ... not least because I was taught to never use them.

Answer (score 1):

[sun.misc.unsafe](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html) is my alltime favorite; the collection of "we needed this to implement things, but really, really don't think you should use it."

Comment: Every good language **should** have an unsafe package in the standard library. Importing this package clearly shows your intent of doing low-level unportable things. The alternatives are: **1-** Having unsafe features in the language itself (C++ for example) and **2-** Having to use a different language such as C for doing low level things (Python and Ruby for example). The unsafe package approach seems much better to me.

Answer (score 1):

Object Orientation (from all statically typed languages). I'll wager this feature has, and will continue, to cost **vastly** more than null pointers. Object Orientation is only good in a dynamic **message passing** language. So it should be dropped from dynamic languages like Python too (since it doesn't use message passing but conventional subroutine calling).

Comment: Python supports (for all intents and purposes) smalltalk's message passing idiom.  It just isn't named that way.  Secondly, I think it's at least a little debatable to call such a pervasive language feature harmful.

Comment: Object Orientation still improves code reuse and code/data encapsulation.  Regardless of the static/dynamic uses of the feature.

Comment: @Orbling: Compared to what? In my opinion functional programming languages have a higher code reuse and i think Haskell's module system is quite good for code/data encapsulation.

Comment: @Lenny222 Compared to standard imperative programming.  I too prefer the functional approach, Haskell is a preferred language of mine.

Comment: @Jason Baker: well certainly it is debatable, but being so pervasive is precisely what makes it so harmful! The OP did ask for my opinion, and I gave it. Just because a bunch of Lemmings jump of a cliff doesn't make the behaviour sane. In this case it is mathematically proven OOP doesn't work, and the correct paradigm is well accepted: category theory is way to represent abstractions (it is in fact the theory of abstractions)

Comment: @Yttrill - I generally am highly skeptical of any theory that depends on most others being lemmings heading to a cliff.  It usually indicates a very egocentric point of view.

Answer (score 1):

[`magic_quotes` in PHP](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php).

Unexperienced developers either rely on it being enabled and thus assume all user input to be escaped for use in a SQL query or rely on it being disabled and thus always escape their input.

When assuming it's enabled and then running the code on a system where it's not it opens gaping wide SQL injection holes.

When assuming it's disabled and it's not, it will result in backslashes being actually stored in the DB, causing ugly/incorrect strings.

There is also no extremely simple way to handle both cases - you need to check if it's enabled using `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` and then apply `stripslashes()` on all values in the `$_*` arrays - since `array_map` is not recursive you need a custom function for this.

Comment: Or you could just use parameterized queries.

Comment: Even then you'll get backslashes if magic quotes are enabled and you didn't expect it.

Answer (score -3):

The language feature that allows programmers to write uncommented or meaningless-commented code.

Comment: And how to fix this?

Comment: @bigown: by implementing comment-or-die feature :D.

Comment: That's called Literate Programming. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming

Comment: That's not a feature, but it is an extremely famous bug in the user front end, most people know it by its latin name: Homo Sapiens.

Answer (score -3):

going out a bit on a limb here - void functions. a function always does something, hence it should either return the result or some other bit of information regarding its success or failure.

Comment: Pascal had procedures (no return value) as well as functions (return value).

Comment: Functions always do something *(well usually, placeholder function anyone?)*, but frequently don't need to tell anyone about it.

Answer (score -4):

POKE in BASIC...

Comment: POKE was awesome.

Comment: In the early days poke was the only reasonable way you could achieve certain things in basic.  Music on an Apple ][ comes to mind...

Comment: You couldn't do much without POKE on a Commodore 64, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Don't forget PEEK, both essential.

Answer (score -5):

I'd have to say garbage collection. It does not eliminate the need to think about memory management, but it eliminates the *perception* of the need to think about memory management, which all too often eliminates the actual thought, and then you get enormous resource hogs and don't know why.  Especially when [the behavior of modern generational GCs could be described without too much hyperbole as "one big memory leak by design" anyway.](http://blog.barrkel.com/2009/12/commonly-confused-tidbits-re-net.html)

Comment: This is simply not true. It is quite possible to write memory-efficient code with a garbage-collected language, and the GC eliminates a big chunk of programmer time (as opposed to program time). Garbage-collected languages have a lot of use-cases and it isn't useful to completely avoid using them.

Comment: @Chinmay: Yes, it's "possible" to, but not common.  Also, it only eliminates programmer time during initial development.  When you've got references left sitting around in some collection somewhere and your memory footprint is way too big, and you've got no leak-tracing tools because you're using a garbage-collected language, you can lose *tons* of programmer time trying to track them down.

Comment: If you've got references sitting around in some collection somewhere, you have other problems.

Comment: So you say, but it's a surprisingly common problem.

Comment: That's why gc'ed languages have weak references :)

Comment: While GC certainly has both strengths and weaknesses, I'd have to say that Mason is a lot more right than wrong on this one. In fact, I've seen people using GC spend a lot of *extra* time on memory management because they ended up trying to hack things after the fact instead of planning for it up front. GC also generally prevents deterministic destruction, which leads to extra work dealing with managing all resources other than memory.

Comment: If resource management is your problem I'd say imposing manual memory management is attacking the wrong problem.  

With manual memory management the malloc() efficiency and heap fragmentation can hurt a lot.  Garbage collection makes new() fast and leaves cleaning up unused memory to a dedicated made-for-purpose background thread.

While resource hogs, leaking references and heap littering still can cause problems, garbage collection still solves more problems than it causes.

Comment: @Asegir: Not really.  Heap fragmentation is only a problem if you're using a really primitive malloc implementation.  Modern memory managers use buckets so the heap doesn't get fragmented.

Comment: I can't believe after years of advancement in GC technology that people still think they are bad. Don't get me wrong, GC free languages have their place but you are a fool if you think they are the right tool for every job.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Am I really a fool if I think that, on a modern multitasking machine, in order to keep paging from trashing your system performance, memory should be released as soon as possible?  No GC has ever managed to even come close to achieving that result, and in fact, the generational garbage collector, which is supposed to be the best, most modern variety there is, does precisely the opposite: for best performance, it has to release memory as *late* as possible.  I don't see that as ever the right tool for any job, not when it slows down my other programs.  Am I a fool for that?

Comment: @Mason - I am sorry if you read that as a direct personal attack. Quite frankly though I feel as if you don't have any idea about the improvements made in GC technology. If I can write a parser that contains zero mutable state and can parse massive source files and maintain under 15MB of memory usage I have to say that the GC is doing a really good job. OK, so maybe you could write one in C that uses 8MB at most... Who cares....?

Comment: @ChaosPandion: OK, fair enough, if all you're doing is parsing source files and using memory in the low double-digits of MB it probably doesn't matter all that much. I tend to inhabit different problem domains, though. At work I maintain a massive enterprise-level inventory and control system for broadcast media. (If you watch TV or listen to the radio in the USA, the station's probably running on software I worked on.) And in my spare time, I like to both play and hack around in video games. In those worlds, the scale of your memory consumption really matters. That's where I'm coming from.

Comment: @Mason - Like I said, the right tool for the job. *(One again, I am sorry for the poor wording in my original comment.)*

Comment: @ChaosPandion: All right. Apology accepted.

Comment: @Mason We've been bitten by this on Solaris 10 and Sun Studio 11, so it can still hurt.  That being said -- the bits of memory we were allocating / freeing were gigabyte-sized, something the memory manager probably wasn't designed to handle.

Comment: A malloc library that uses heaps and buckets is just one step away from a generational garbage collector. It's already managing the pool for you and trying to be intelligent about allocating/deallocating resources. A call to free() almost certainly doesn't release it back to the OS; it just goes back in the pool. Because of the pool management, I think it would be difficult to say that calls to malloc() and free() have deterministic performance.

Comment: @Barry: It's deterministic within the program.  If I'm done with a 5 KB block of memory, then ask for another 5 KB soon afterwards, what happens?  In a garbage collected system, it needs to request a new 5 KB block, even though there's a perfectly good block sitting unused, unless the GC has run in the interim, in which case you can recycle the old block.  With malloc and free, you'll always be able to recycle the old block.  Multiply this by a few hundred thousand and it becomes a real issue.

Comment: People who don't think about memory management will (not) do that regardless of whether they have a garbage collector or not. I've seen a lot of leaky Delphi code. GC's protect bad programmers from themselves (partly), and don't get in the way of good programmers (who end up writing identical code anyway, cleaning up stuff right after they use it).

Comment: @Joeri: **Should bad programmers be protected?** I realise that's another question, but really - this whole question here revolves around the need to shield computers from poor coders.  I say leave the power and the risk and let the poorer coders get fired making the profession stronger.

Comment: @Orbling: Should cars have ABS, power steering and navigation systems? To me compilers and IDE's are just programs with their own set of end-users. There's no such thing as a programmer, there are only degrees of sophistication in users. Software should be user-friendly. Not including useful features because they only are necessary for "noobs" is elitist, and imho a sign of bad craftsmanship.

Comment: @Joeri You are welcome to your opinion, I however firmly believe in elitism in professions.  There are definitely programmers, as there are doctors and pilots.  You would not want a non-professional performing heart surgery on you, and I for one do not like e-commerce websites for instance being built by non-experts; it is dangerous - there should be compulsory certification.  On your driving example, I have always said driving should be a profession and restricted to experts - the road fatality rates as the leading cause of death in young adults attest to that.

Comment: I agree that for some classes of software we need mechanisms of certification to ensure the software is built the right way, like we require mandatory safety testing for cars. However, we were talking about removing garbage collecting from all programming languages, and I don't think that helps you get one step closer to better software. On the contrary, you'd just get the same people building software that doesn't clean up after itself and is less reliable as a result. The problem is not technical, it's sociological. It cannot be solved through technology.

Answer (score -5):

C, and definitely C++: Pointer arithmetic.  Allowing people to convert integers into memory addresses is asking for trouble.

And maybe even raw access to pointers altogether?

In C++ you have references that makes pointers almost completely unnecessary.  For the remaining cases smart pointers should be considered mandatory.

Java is also proves that you *can* make a programming language that uses pointers without allowing people access to the pointer value itself.

Apart from `null` ... but that's a different story.

Comment: Pointers, while difficult to use properly at times, are very necessary for a great number of efficient memory operations.

Comment: True.  But allowing people to convert integers into memory references on a regular basis, or adding numbers to memory addresses is mostly harmful these days in my opinion.

In C++ you have references as a perfectly good alternative, and smart pointers / auto pointers for when you really need it to be a pointer.

Comment: This answer is *only* valid if you are working on a software stack constructed to hide pointers. In *all* other cases, this answer is wrong.

Comment: *Some* programming language needs to have pointers available so you can write all the operating systems and virtual machines for the other programming languages.

Comment: -1. There is a reason you need ptr arithmetic: Iterating a point is fast than indexing. `for(int i=0;i<SIZE;++i) ++arr[i]` is slower than `for(int*i=arr;i<arr+SIZE;++i)*i++`.  All java managed to prove is that you do need pointer, or have you never looked at `sun.misc.Unsafe`? If you don't need pointers, please explain how to write a generic swap function using Java. (e.g. int a=1,b=2; swap(a,b); assert( a==2 && b==1); ). Not to mention all the problems in c/c++ you'd have if you HAD to use references. How would you call a virtual function on an opaque struct w/o pointers?

Comment: fennec: For accessing hardware -- true, you need to be able to deal with specific address values.

Comment: kts: The former is much more readable than the latter, and if the latter is faster I'd blame that on the CPU or the compiler, not the language feature. 

`sun.misc.Unsafe` is _not_ part of the Java language or the Java standard library.  It's an internal Sun JVM implementation class not meant for public consumption.

As for the need of a swap it's not something I miss on a regular basis.

Comment: If you had said allowing integer type variables to be used for pointer arithmetic uncast to a pointer type, then yes, I'd agree - half the problems with getting code converted to x64 are down to pointer type issues.  Pointer arithmetic itself is a necessary and useful feature, but dangerous, power is dangerous.